# convert lower case to Upper case in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, foreign-keys

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Indexes/Index">
      <xsl:value-of select="Caption" />:
      <xsl:value-of select="Description" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

convert lower case to Upper case in XSLT

Answer (score 1):

In **XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Caption, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />:
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Description, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
```

in **XSLT 2.0** you can also use below

```
<xsl:value-of select="upper-case(Caption)" />:
<xsl:value-of select="upper-case(Description)" />
```

Comment: Error:  upper-case is unknown XSLT function

Comment: That suggests you are using an XSLT processor that does not support XSLT 2.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr to find out what processor and xslt version you do have.

Comment: In your XSLT 1.0 example you forgot the lower case q.

Comment: @DickBos, Thanks for highlighting.